# How to make a parallel connection between two components when each has its own voltage?

Tags: switches, logic-level

I have a problem to determine whether or not it is safe to make a connection as picture below. Currently I have a H7EC counter connected to a switch and it has 2.7 V  across terminal 1 & 2 on the counter itself (it should be a battery inside the counter). I was planning to branch out the connection parallel to PC COM port and there's 5.8 V across pin 2 & 3 of the PC COM port.

My question is: Is it safe if I make the connection directly as the picture? If not, what do I need to add in between so it won't do any damage to the counter/COM port?

[image]

Comment: That looks like a bad idea. A 2-pole switch is the easy solution.

Comment: Or a single pole switch driving a double pole relay if your desired double pole switcyh doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

The amount of current that can be drawn from a COM port is not part of its specification.  You would need to look up your individual COM port's drivers and find out how much current they can provide.

Practically speaking, you can pull 10-20mA without trouble, as [serial mice](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/rs232-output-current-rating.64294/) used power from these signal lines to power the mouse, and they operated in this range.  To be safe, I'd put resistance in the line to ensure you cannot exceed those currents with the voltages available.

From V=IR, R=V/I = 5.8V/10mA = 580ohm

So if you have 580 ohms of resistance between your power sources and your sinks, you will stay within the range that they are typically designed for.